# How to show/hide a background image of a <td> on hover of a <tr> without using useState

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

What I want to happen is to show/hide a background-image inside the first `<td>` while hovering over the whole table row without adding any states. I think I can just use some css selectors and use the `:hover` of the `<tr/>` to handle it. Not sure where to go from here though.

The behavior I expect:

- show a background-image in a `<td>` when a user is not hovering over a `<tr>`
- hide the background-image on hover of the whole `<tr>`

[Here's a gif of what I expect it to look like](https://gph.is/g/aR8wkNO)

What I've tried so far is to add a div inside the td and add a background image. However, I am unsure of how I can trigger a hover for the `<tr/>` and then change the td's style to add `visibility: hidden;` on the div inside the `<td/>`

[Here's a simple codesandbox link of what I've tried so far](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-sid-zpde6?file=/src/App.js)

Pasting the code from the sandbox

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Header</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <StyledTD>
              <TableDataBackground />
              checkbox placholder
            </StyledTD>
            <td> Some person </td>
            <td> this is their data</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

const StyledTD = styled.td`
  position: relative;
`;

const TableDataBackground = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-image: url("http://assets.stickpng.com/images/58afdad6829958a978a4a693.png");
  background-size: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
`;
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Got it! Just updated the question & pasted the code. was pretty short anyway. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Your code does not work as a [mcve]

Comment: Why do you want to use an image to display a circle ? Why you do not use CSS direclty to create a circle with border-radius: 50%; and then display it when you hover the table row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

https://codesandbox.io/s/so-67255819-hyubp?file=/src/App.js

### Explanation

I forked your codesandbox and made some additions to the styled components.

1. Assuming you're rendering your table with the background image elements already in place, I set the default display as `display: none;`.
2. I used styled-components' [referring to other components](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components) approach to select the `TableDataBackground` component from within the `Table` component, when the `tr` is hovered. **Note:** I had to move the declaration of `TableDataBackground` *before* `Table` so that I could select it.

**Edit:** In the codesandbox, I reversed the `display` values since I re-read your question and it says to show the image when **not** hovering.

Comment: This works! Thanks for linking the doc too!